# How can I print object data from SimpleXMLElement Object?

Tags: php, xml

I am using php.
How can I get data(0d07d7d9-ccc2-4a3b-8feb-51eea7420056) from below object

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0d07d7d9-ccc2-4a3b-8feb-51eea7420056 )
```

Comment: Did you try `echo $yourobject[0];` ?

Comment: Yes I tried but same object displayed as it is :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `echo $yourobject[0];` would work. Besides.. you could make use of a `foreach` construct to print the values too..

```
foreach($yourobject as $val)
{
 echo $val;
}
```